# jQuery Scope of Events Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a page that has a table but I wanted to give the users the choice to make one of the fields editable.

In one of the cells I have

```
<a class='noteedit'><i class='material-icons blue-text'>edit</i></a>
```

In my JS I have

```
$(".noteedit").click(function(){
    obj = $(this).parent().parent(); // get entire row
    cell = $(obj).find("td:eq(1)"); // get current value of cell
    $(obj).find("td:eq(2)").remove(); // remove adjacent cell
    cell.replaceWith("<td><form><input name='noteedit' value='" + cell.text() +"'></td><td><a onclick=\"$(this).parent().parent().find('form').submit();\"  class='noteeditsubmit'><i class='material-icons green-text'>send</i></a><a  class='noteeditcancel'><i class='material-icons grey-text'>cancel</i></a></form></td>") // Change cell to become a form and change adjacent cell be the submit button.
    $(".noteeditcancel").click(function(){
        // Convert cell from <form> to just its original value
        // Change Submit/Cancel icon to original Edit button
    });
});
```

The problem is once I convert the cell value to the original Edit button, I cannot click the button anymore because the event binding is not in the scope.

So, how can I fix this and have a better solution than what I am currently doing now.

My goal is to have an edit button that converts cell to a submittable form but also have a cancel button to revert back to original value

Comment: click event handler inside another click event handler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on hev1's answer, this syntax allows you to create event listeners for whatever matches your query under the scope of `document`, which is everything. You can change `document` to a narrow query if you want.

```
$(document).on('click', '.noteedit', function(){
    //might as well do the same for your edit button
});
$(document).on('click', '.noteeditcancel', function(){
    // again, any class of 'noteeditcancel' under the scope of document, even if created dynamically, will listen
});
```

Comment: This solution worked out the best for my use case because 0 modification of my code blocks were needed. I just had to change the call to be `$(document).on('click', 'XXX'...`

Answer (score 1):

You should not have an event handler inside another event handler. You can use `$(document).on('click', '.noeeditcancel', function(){})` to listen for click events for all elements with a class of `noeeditcancel` (even dynamically created ones). You can listen for events on all elements matching your query in the document this way.

```
$(".noteedit").click(function(){
    obj = $(this).parent().parent(); // get entire row
    cell = $(obj).find("td:eq(1)"); // get current value of cell
    $(obj).find("td:eq(2)").remove(); // remove adjacent cell
    cell.replaceWith("<td><form><input name='noteedit' value='" + cell.text() +"'></td><td><a onclick=\"$(this).parent().parent().find('form').submit();\"  class='noteeditsubmit'><i class='material-icons green-text'>send</i></a><a  class='noteeditcancel'><i class='material-icons grey-text'>cancel</i></a></form></td>") 
});
$(document).on('click', '.noteeditcancel', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Example which may help you:

```js
var oldValues = {};

$(".noteedit").click(function() {
  var uniqueSelector = $(this).closest('tr').index();
  var cell = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)');
  oldValues[uniqueSelector] = cell.text();
  cell.html(`<form><input name='noteedit' value="${oldValues[uniqueSelector]}" onchange="inputChanged(this)"></form>`);
  $(this).toggle().siblings().toggle();
});



$(".noteeditcancel").click(function(e) {
  var uniqueSelector = $(this).closest('tr').index();
  var cell = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)');
  cell.html(oldValues[uniqueSelector]);
  delete oldValues[uniqueSelector];
  $(this).toggle().siblings().toggle();
});

function inputChanged($this) {
  var uniqueSelector = $($this).closest('tr').index();
  oldValues[uniqueSelector] = $($this).val();
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.noteeditsubmit,
.noteeditcancel {
  display: none
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  border-color: #84c4ff;
  padding: 4px 15px
}

td {
  padding: 2px 4px
}

tbody th {
  width: 180px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a class='noteedit'><i class='material-icons blue-text'></i> edit</a>
        <a onclick="$(this).parent().parent().find('form').submit()" class='noteeditsubmit'><i class='material-icons green-text'>send</i></a>
        <a class='noteeditcancel'><i class='material-icons grey-text'>cancel</i></a>
      </th>
      <td>Mark</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a class='noteedit'><i class='material-icons blue-text'></i> edit</a>
        <a onclick="$(this).parent().parent().find('form').submit()" class='noteeditsubmit'><i class='material-icons green-text'>send</i></a>
        <a class='noteeditcancel'><i class='material-icons grey-text'>cancel</i></a>
      </th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a class='noteedit'><i class='material-icons blue-text'></i> edit</a>
        <a onclick="$(this).parent().parent().find('form').submit()" class='noteeditsubmit'><i class='material-icons green-text'>send</i></a>
        <a class='noteeditcancel'><i class='material-icons grey-text'>cancel</i></a>
      </th>
      <td>Larry</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could nest the two click events into each other

```
$('.noteedit').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();

    // Your code here 
    $(document).on('click', '.noteeditcancel', function(e) {
    // Your follow up code here 
  });
});
```